# One to many association not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My model is

```
class TelecomOperator < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :telecom_operator
```

When I do **TelecomOperator.first.users** it gives me all users but When I do
**User.first.telecom_operator** it always give me nil

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
=> nil
```

When I do

```
User.includes(:telecom_operator).find(2)
```

It works fine

Comment: Check the spelling. It should be `User.first.telecom_operator`. You are missing **a** in **operator**.

Comment: Even including "a" same issue

Comment: May be that particular user has no telecom_opeartor. Check if there any record in telecom_operators table matching that foreign_key value in users table

Comment: seems you have `"users"."deleted_at"` with not null value for id=2. please validate your default scope.